# Unit test a singleton class with MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, singleton

I want to test my class `EventTextsDB` that is a singleton, using MSTest in .NET 6.

I first thought about using `AppDomain`, but they basically were removed in .NET 5+ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#application-domains)
Then I found [Unit test singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998176/unit-test-singletons), but by calling the private constructor via reflection I still cannot test the `static Create()` and `static Delete()` methods in the class, because they set the `static EventTextsDB Instance` property.

I could use ordered unit tests, but this would require a lot of work because I would have to order all tests that used this class. Not many tests use or test this class yet, but many do with a similar class `LanguageDB`, at which I want to apply the same solution that I am looking for.

I have read somewhere on stackoverflow or MSDN, that each test assembly runs isolated (in different `AppDomain`, if they still exist?), but I don't want to create 10 new test assemblies just for 10 tests of this class.

How can I test my singleton class?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection? If yes, you could refactor your class to a non-singleton and let the DI container handle its lifetime.

Comment: @mu88 No, I'm not using that.